# Unable to create new TableSchema in BigQuery with C#

Tags: google-bigquery, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to create Google BigQuery Table Schema Explicitly, TableSchema.Fields.Add() method throws Object Reference Exception.

```
        TableSchema Schema = response.Schema;

        TableFieldSchema sc1 = new TableFieldSchema();
        sc1.Name = "CustomerID";
        sc1.Type = "STRING";
        sc1.Mode = "NULLABLE";

        Schema.Fields.Add(sc1); -- Throws Error.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I think you are supposed to build new Schema in order to mutate it, not to use one from response object.

Comment: @Mosha Pasumansky, Exactly.  I am trying to load CSV file into new table, so that i want to create TableSchema for that purpose, but not able to build new schema using above methods.  Do you have any samples to build new schema using Google BigQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can able to create new TableSchema in .NET client library by using below code.

```
TableSchema Schema = new TableSchema();
TableFieldSchema F1 = new TableFieldSchema();
F1.Name = "COLUMN NAME";
F1.Type = "STRING";
F1.Mode = "REQUIRED";

TableFieldSchema F2 = new TableFieldSchema();
F1.Name = "COLUMN NAME";
F1.Type = "INTEGER";
F1.Mode = "NULLABLE";

//Add N number of fields as per your needs

System.Collections.Generic.IList<TableFieldSchema> FS = new System.Collections.Generic.List<TableFieldSchema>();
FS.Add(F1);
FS.Add(F2);

Schema.Fields = FS;
```